# VB.net change ComboBox selected value and display

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code in vb.net:

```
Function GetBillingMonthsGrouped() As List(Of BillingMonthsGrouped)
        Dim conn = New MySqlConnection()
        Dim conn2 = New MySqlConnection()
        Dim myCommand, myCommand2 As New MySqlCommand
        Dim reader, reader2 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim SQL As String

        conn.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "
        conn2.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "

        Dim billingMonthsGrouped = New List(Of BillingMonthsGrouped)

        'customers
        conn.Open()
        SQL = "select MONTH(timestamp) from billing group by MONTH(timestamp) order by MONTH(timestamp) ASC "
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            billingMonthsGrouped.Add(New BillingMonthsGrouped(reader.GetString(0), MonthName(reader.GetString(0))))
        End While
        conn.Close()

        Return billingMonthsGrouped
    End Function
    Public Class BillingMonthsGrouped
        Public Sub New(ByVal id As String, ByVal name As String)
            mID = id
            mName = name
        End Sub

        Private mID As String
        Public Property ID() As String
            Get
                Return mID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                mID = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private mName As String
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return mName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                mName = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

and then this part:

```
ComboBox3.DataSource = GetBillingMonthsGrouped()
ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox3.ValueMember = "ID"
ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
```

What code would i need to use to change the selected value of `ComboBox3` to be the current month

I tried using:

```
ComboBox3.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
```

but that doesn't change the selected value. I need to have the value as the month number and the display as the month name

Comment: Before you used `ComboBox3.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")`, what were the available values in the combobox? Please specify all key/value pairs that were available before you attempted SelectedValue change. Also, what was the value of `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")` at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that the comboBox already having the months, you need to set current month as selected. then in this situation you can use the following code to select `current month` as selected month

```
  ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Now.Month
```

If you want to display one month only means you can use the code:

```
  ComboBox1.SelectedText = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM")
```

Comment: the combox box does not display all 12 months, just the ones that are available